# Insert value into auto-inc/identity column higher than current auto-inc/identity value

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, sql-insert

**Details**

I couldn't find any info regarding this issue on SE or MySQL docs.

I have encountered a situation where I may need to insert an auto-inc value higher than the current value. For example, the auto-inc column is currently at 12 & I need to insert a row with the auto-inc field at 15.

**Questions**

1 - If I was to simply just do this insert, would it clash once the auto-inc hits 15 or would the next value inserted start at 16? I was told the latter is how it works by a friend. However, in the docs I came across a statement that it would cause it to clash later on. Would I have to reseed the table to 16 after doing this?

2 - What is a best practice in a situation like this?

Please, let me know if any other information should be provided.

Comment: A scenario which requires you to modify a primary key means you're doing something wrong with your application design. There doesn't exist a scenario in this world where you **have** to insert 15 as auto_increment if you had 12 as last one. If you arrived at the conclusion or requirement where you have to do so, you have to know you're doing something so wrong that it will cause you such a headache in the future that you'll curse the day you came up with it. I suggest that you describe your **real** problem, not the solution that you came up with.

Comment: The problem I have stated is the problem I am facing. However, you are correct - this is a result of a mistake in deployment. We accidentally deployed a site with development db configuration. Now I need to transfer db data from dev to production and retain relationships. I know how to simply insert data using null for the id, etc.. I want to know how the situation I've described can be solved.

Comment: 1) Disable identity, insert new value, reseed identity to new High+ growth factor 2) Best practice: improve Quality Assurance / control.  Shouldn't happen.

Comment: :/ I know.. was definitely an issue with workflow. But what happens happens and needs to be figured out. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, inserting a value higher than the current increment has the effect of adjusting the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value in your database. That is, inserting 20 will set it to 21. I'm fairly certain this behaviour is consistent in newer versions of MySQL.

You can see the current increment with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted to hear. However, my friend said the same thing - "I think/fairly certain". Since this is mission critical, I wanted more confidence and as a result have been researching the whole day so far! We are using **MySQL** 5.5. How confident are you? Have you found a resource - I am struggling to find docs regarding this.

Comment: Let's put it this way: I've never seen it not behave that way in single-master, non-cluster systems. If you're using multi-master, NDB, or anything exotic, all bets are off. You can try testing this yourself to be sure it works on your platform.

Comment: Tadman, could you perhaps offer advice on the bigger issue also? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78591/transfer-relational-data-from-one-db-to-another-production-db-currently-populate

Answer (score 1):

Just tried it.

1) the auto-inc will be set to 16, it wont cause any problem.

2) I would assume the best practise is to leave the auto-inc column work alone but i cannot see any problem not doing so. However if the column has primary or unique key, inserting with a value for the column might cause a problem if the value is already in the database.

Hope it helped !

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, but tadman beat you to it :( + 1 anyways. Might be useful for future viewers to know which MySQL version(s) does this. The column is a primary-key auto-inc, hence the problem described shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: haha, no worries, glad it helped. I use MySQL v5.6.20 but i really do not think that it depends on the version. If you use it in a primary key column be careful to use the right values